# Visual Studio 2012 Crashing viewing aspx pages

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

VS is Crashing viewing aspx pages Visual Studio I get this exception. This is the exception from the event log:

```
Application: devenv.exe (Visual Studio Premium 2012)
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
Stack:
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsExpansionManager.EnumerateExpansions(System.Guid, Int32, System.String[], Int32, Int32, Int32, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsExpansionEnumeration ByRef)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Snippets.SnippetListManager+SnippetCache.CacheLanguageExpansionStructs(Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsExpansionManager, System.Guid)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Snippets.SnippetListManager+SnippetCache..ctor(Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsExpansionManager, System.Guid, SnippetCache)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Snippets.SnippetListManager.ResetSnippetCache(System.Guid)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Snippets.SnippetListManager.EnsureInitialized(System.Guid)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Snippets.SnippetListManager.GetInstance(System.Guid)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Factory.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Interop.IMVWFactory.CreateSnippetListManager(System.Guid)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IOleInPlaceComponent.FDoIdle(UInt32)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.OleInPlaceComponentIdleManager.PassOnIdleTime(System.Collections.Generic.List`1<Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IOleInPlaceComponent>, Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.OleComponentSupport.IdleTypes)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.OleInPlaceComponentIdleManager.FDoIdleCore(UInt32)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.OleComponentSupport.OleComponent.Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IOleComponent.FDoIdle(UInt32)
```

I have:

```
 - Started Visual Studio in Safe Mode
 - Reverted my settings to default
 - Repaired
 - Done a uninstall and reinstall
```

Anyone else have any ideas ?

Comment: My first thought is IE10. Did you, by chance, install that recently? It totally screwed up javascript debugging on my system, but I didn't wait around to see what else may have been broke.

Comment: I was able to uninstall IE10, repair install VS2012, re-install VS Update 1 and everything was fine.

Comment: I still have IE 9 installed but I will look to see if any other updates were installed

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the expansion manager (unmanaged component). This is responsible notably for VS's snippet expansion. You could track the registry, for example, this key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0_Config\Languages\CodeExpansions and check all the sub keys, see if something looks bad, the directories, or even the .XML files pointed at. You could also kill theses keys and repair. Good luck.

Comment: @SimonMourier I tried it again when getting back from lunch and it isn't working still I got an idea that goes along with yours if it works I'll still give you the credit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a bug in the expansion manager (an unmanaged component of Visual Studio).
It is responsible notably for Visual Studio's snippet expansion feature.

You could track the registry, for example, this key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0_Config\Languages\CodeExpa‌​nsions
```

and check all the sub keys, see if something looks bad, the directories, or even the .XML files (containing snippet configurations) pointed at. You can also use SysInternals' ProcMon tool to monitor what's going on.

Ultimately, you could also kill all these keys and launch a repair...

It's also possible to report the bug to Microsoft here: [Connect site for Visual Studio](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio) but if it's not easily reproducible, it may not be fixed in a near future.

Comment: I looked at that key and found nothing ... but this gave me a idea and that was to totally delete my user account profile and start from scratch http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/fix-a-corrupted-user-profile (this is for windows Vista but works for 7 as well) Thanks @Simon great thinking!